# 'StandardKernel' is obsolete: `Use StandardKernelConfiguration and StandardReadonlyKernel`

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, console-application, ninject

I want to use ninject (version 4.0.0) to resolve dependencies in my Windows Service program, I have seen [quite](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-inject-using-ninject-ioc-in-console-application/) [a](http://www.martinsteel.co.uk/blog/2014/Ninject-dependency-injection-for-windows-services) [few](https://medium.com/the-liberators/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4) [tutorials](http://techflask.com/step-by-step-dependency-injection-tutorial/), and they all use `StandardKernel` to initialize ninject Kernel as below:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

But I am getting the following warning when using `StandardKernel`:

> 'StandardKernel' is obsolete: 'Use StandardKernelConfiguration and
>   StandardReadonlyKernel'

Can anyone give an example using `StandardKernelConfiguration` and `StandardReadonlyKernel`?

Comment: I am still looking for some concrete examples, but I tend to check the tests for examples of how to use libraries with outdated documentation. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject.Test/Unit/KernelConfigurationTests.cs

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Nkosi: thanks for your help... I just noticed that I have mistakenly installed ninject 4.0.0 which is in beta... I will revert back to 3.3.4 (which is the latest stable) and see if I get the same warning

Comment: I am also not finding those types in the repository. there is `KernelConfiguration` and `ReadonlyKernel`

Comment: I reverted back to 3.3.4 and warning went away, but the following syntax works for version 4: `IReadOnlyKernel readOnlyKernel = new KernelConfiguration(new SyncerModule()).BuildReadonlyKernel();` updated the question, and sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not realized that ninject version 4.0.0 is in beta, but the following syntax worked for me:

```
IReadOnlyKernel kernel = new KernelConfiguration(new MyModule()).BuildReadonlyKernel();
```